# How to correctly use an adjustable desk?

Tags: ergonomics, lifestyle, office

I've just got an adjustable desk at my office that I wanted for a long time, since I live most of my life at the computer. I read that sitting for extended periods is quite harmful for health. [1](http://www.nchpad.org/403/2216/Sedentary~Lifestyle~is~Dangerous~to~Your~Health)  [2](http://dadun.unav.edu/bitstream/10171/17482/1/International%20Journal%20of%20Epidemiology%202003.pdf) In fact, I experienced some problems myself, and I'm not exactly old.

On the other hand, now I'm standing at my new desk, and I realize it's quite hard on my lower legs, because I'm too heavy.

My assumption is that I must find the optimal balance between sitting and standing, depending on my body size and weight. The question is how I do that?