# is there evidence that determines the appropriate amount of standing time in a day?

Tags: ergonomics, position, office, standing, sitting

The closest question I was able to find from my search results was [How to correctly use an adjustable desk?](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/3885/how-to-correctly-use-an-adjustable-desk) that was asked almost a year ago with no answers.  That said, I spend anywhere from eight to sixteen hours a day at my desk sitting.  Recently I purchased an adjustable smart desk that I will configure a plist to fire on my Mac that will tell the adjustable desk to move in X position at a set time interval.

That said, I've been looking for any evidence that states when is the appropriate time to stand or sit in the morning?  As in, after I first wake-up from my slumber would it be healthier on the body to start the day in a standing position?

Several years ago I experienced a very bad back accident and I've been looking for any documentation or writings on how to properly span the amount of standing and sitting intervals.  When I refer to intervals I mean is there a healthier benefit when scripting the desk adjustment to hourly or in two hour intervals?

Answer (score 1):

Aren't you in luck, I asked a very similar question over in physical fitness SE:

https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/31109/how-effective-are-standing-desks

Here is the top answer:

> A recent meta-analysis of 23 published studies is MacEwen, MacDonald,
>   and Burr, "A systematic review of standing and treadmill desks in the
>   workplace," *Preventative Medicine* **70**(January 2015):50-58.
>
> The article is here:   http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.ypmed.2014.11.011
>
> Quoting from the paper's summary:
>
> > Treadmill desks led to the greatest improvement in physiological outcomes including postprandial glucose, HDL cholesterol, and
> >     anthropometrics, while standing desk use was associated with few
> >     physiological changes. Standing and treadmill desks both showed mixed
> >     results for improving psychological well-being with little impact on
> >     work performance.