# Walking and running for venis varicose

Tags: blood-vessels, swelling, walking, varicose-veins, exertion

[Veins varicose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Varicose_veins) occurs in the people, who walk slowly (slow walking is also known as "standing" and [there is a question](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/8798) asking for how much of slow walking is bad) for the long time. I however see that [walking and running are used to prevent it](http://www.wikihow.com/Prevent-Varicose-Veins#step_1_4). It is confusing. Is there a minimal speed that demarcates between standing and walking? Is there a maximum walking time limit after which walking changes from preventing varicose to causing it?

I see that my veins swell and stick quite out after a 12-hour walk. Is it ok? Can I go hiking? How far and long (it terms of distance and time) can I walk and run in one iteration, without taking a break?